# JSF expression language (EL) question

Tags: jsf, el

I have a menu item that I want to show/hide only if the user has certain roles.

I'm using the rendered attribute for this, but I'm stuck on something.  This works ...

```
rendered="#{loginHandler.hasStaffRole}"
```

... but this does not ...

```
rendered="#{loginHandler.hasStaffRole or loginHandler.hasInstructorRole or loginHandler.hasVolunteerRole}"
```

The error I get in Eclipse for the problem one is:

"cannot apply expression operators to method bindings"

Any idea how I should fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question.  The problem was the LoginHandler.hasStaffRole() method needed to be worded LoginHandler.isHasStaffRole() in order to be recognized as a property.  (In the end I changed it to .isUserHasStaffRole.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:
`rendered="#{user.canEdit or user.isRole('ROLE_1', 'ROLE_2')}"`

The "solution" for my Eclipse 4.3 was to reverse the arguments:    `rendered="#{user.isRole('ROLE_1', 'ROLE_2') or user.canEdit}"`

Adding parentheses did not cure it.
Your mileage may vary.